# How important is InnoDB versus MyISAM?

Tags: innodb, myisam

Does it really matter if the default storage engine is InnoDB? My default storage engine is MyISAM

Comment: This could easily be investigated by Googling. If you have more specific questions, get back to us. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this could be solved by Googling. If you need more specific information or have a problem with what you learn by Googling, then get back to us. MyISAM is being deprecated - even for system tables in 5.7. Lose it ASAP.

Comment: When I searched for this question the similar one did not show up. No problem to close. I read the answers to the prior question, and it is much more thoroughly answered here. Appreciate it.

Comment: Don't hesitate to get back to us if you're still unclear. Check out the forum tour and the "help us to help you" blog, both at the bottom left of the page. These forums are a great resource and you will get all the more out of them if you follow the guidelines - p.s. welcome to the forum :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many differences.  The biggest for me is that InnoDB supports foreign keys MyISAM does not.

Some will argue that MyIsam is faster for reads,  but if you want to take advantage of compression for example you need Innodb.

My default position is to start with InnoDB whenever possible,  then if you cannot use this for example when using spatial features then use MyISAM.

The most concise post on this can be found over at Percona.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/01/12/should-you-move-from-myisam-to-innodb/

Hope this is of use